Applications windows do not open (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my new HP laptop.
I am encountering a problem after installing several applications. The installation appears to be successful, but when I click on the application icon, no window appears. This issue only occurs with certain applications, such as Thunderbird and Zoom. Other applications work fine.
A few additional details: I tried installing Thunderbird using both the package manager and apt-get install thunderbird. Both methods resulted in the same issue. When I switch between tabs using ALT+TAB, I can see the Thunderbird window, but when I select it, it just disappears.
Can anyone help me with this?
